# Javascript 'this' pointer in jQuery

Tags: javascript, pointers, this

I've created an object `obj`:

```
function a(id, ...){
   this.id = id;
   ......
}
```

`var obj = new a("#somediv", ...);`

and I have this function:

```
a.prototype.b = function(){
    $(this.id+" span").mouseover(function(){
        $(this.id).addClass("c");
    });

};
```

Apparently, the `this` in the mouseover function points to the `span` instead of `obj`...

I know I can solve this problem by creating a variable and getting the property of `this.id` but

**is there a way to make the `this` in the mouseover function point to `obj` instead?**

Comment: Note that JS doesn't have pointers, at least not in the traditional sense that, e.g., C does. (You can't do any kind of pointer arithmetic, you can pass references as params but can't update which object the original variable referred to, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pure JavaScript in newer browsers, you can bind the function:

```
a.prototype.b = function(){
    $(this.id+" span").mouseover(function(){
        $(this.id).addClass("c");
    }.bind(this));
};
```

With jQuery, you can get better browser support:

```
a.prototype.b = function(){
    $(this.id+" span").mouseover($.proxy(function(){
        $(this.id).addClass("c");
    }, this));
};
```

Comment: As a note about `bind` vs `proxy`, `foo.bind(bar) !== foo.bind(bar)` which means that you'll need to store a reference to the bound function if you want to remove the event handler, however if you use jQuery's `$.proxy`, jQuery is able to unbind "identical" proxies of a function (`$.proxy(foo, bar) !== $.proxy(foo, bar)`, however the returned function will have a GUID that jQuery can use to match proxies of the same function).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `$.proxy`:

```
a.prototype.b = function(){
    $(this.id+" span").mouseover($.proxy(function(){
        $(this.id).addClass("c");
    }, this));
};
```